# Jquery Scroll to ID offset: Different offsets between desktop and mobile

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using the following JavaScript for scrolling to an ID on a one page site (https://deganiagroup.com/) and my issue is this script does work but the sticky header I'm using has slightly different heights between desktop and mobile. So I need this to work on both. Right now, the following settings are exclusively for mobile. Is there some kind of if else statement I can add to make this work for different browser widths?

Should mention that this is a WordPress site using the Elementor page builder plugin.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
    if ( ! defined( 'ELEMENTOR_VERSION' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            // Add space for Elementor Menu Anchor link
             $( window ).on( 'elementor/frontend/init', function() {
                elementorFrontend.hooks.addFilter( 'frontend/handlers/menu_anchor/scroll_top_distance', function( scrollTop ) {
                    return scrollTop - 121; // Height of header on mobile
                } );
            } );
        } );
    </script>
    <?php
} );
```

Comment: Dynamically identify the height of header and apply that `scrollTop - dynamicHeadHeight`

Comment: Is this your problem? - https://ibb.co/vLDx4jz

Comment: No. Go Click on Services and watch on both desktop and mobile. You'll see the difference.